# How to identify a 2.4Ghz RF chip from LED panel remote (Albrillo)

Tags: microcontroller, rf, integrated-circuit, remote-control, nrf24l01

I am attempting to identify two chips used in a remote control that enables the use of LED panels. I am trying to automate the turn on/turn off without using the remote by emitting the same RF message with NRF24l01.

However, I have no clue about what the RF generating chip is and how it operates.

There are no markings on the chip itself.

Additionally, there is another chip which I assume is a form of microcontroller that operates I/O from the buttons.

The remote claims to operate in the 2.4GHz range (which is why I choose NRF24). There is some form of protocol/encoding which separates the remotes from panels (I have 4 remotes that won't interfere with each other communicating to their panels)

My assumption is that the chip marked JH001Y (picture 4) is likely to be the microcontroller/ I/O carrier because the other controller links directly to an open-ended circuit path which I assume is the antenna (see picture 3).

So what are those ICs or do you have any suggestions on how to identify them?

Some pictures here of the device, PCB and ICs.

Remote enclosure:
[image]

PCB:
[image]
[image]

Microcontroller?:
[image]

2.4GHz transmitter?:
[image]

Comment: why do you believe that an NRF24l01 would be able to generate the same signal as the remote control?

Comment: investigate `software defined radio` or `SDR`

Comment: i suspect that the remote control generates an RF signal that is similar to an IR remote control signal ... if you have access to an oscilloscope, then use it

Comment: What do you see when you fire up your spectrum analyser? That's more relevant than pictures of unmarked ICs and keyboards...